# Trying to refactor code but getting run time error

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to refactor my code below to increase the performance of UpdateSites(). GetNewSite() takes about 500ms, and there will be multiple sites UpdateSites() is processing. My idea is to run the fetches in parallel. When I test my solution, Visual Studio gives me the error:

`Visual Studio Just-In-Time Debugger
An unhandled Microsoft .NET Framework exception occurred in w3wp.exe [3656]. Just-In-Time debugging this exception failed with the following error: No installed debugger has Just-In-Time debugging enabled. In Visual Studio, Just-In-Time debugging can be enabled from Tools/Options/Debugging/Just-In-Time.`

Running my program with my Original code does not trigger an error. Did I do a bad refactoring job?

```
// original
await UpdateSites(currentUserSites);
private async Task<List<Site>> UpdateSites(List<Site> sites)
{
    foreach (var site in sites)
    {
        var newSite = await GetNewSite(site.SiteId);
        site.address = newSite.address;
        site.phone = newSite.phone;
    }
    return sites;
}


// refactored
UpdateSites(currentUserSites);
private void UpdateSites(List<Site> sites)
{
    Parallel.ForEach(sites, async site =>
    {
        var newSite = await GetNewSite(site.SiteId);
        site.address = newSite.address;
        site.phone = newSite.phone;
    });
}
```

Comment: I read the message and it looks like you need to install the JIT debugger to get enough information to solve the problem.

Comment: Have you tried enabling Just-In-Time debugging  from Tools/Options/Debugging/Just-In-Time in Visual Studio?

Comment: You shouldn't be using an `async` method inside a `Parallel.ForEach` it doesn't support it. You can use `sites.Select(async => ....)` instead for parallel execution.

Comment: Let me try installing JIT as I cannot find it under Tools/Options...

Comment: @JSteward How would I include `site.address = newSite.address` in your proposed solution? Would you be able to reply as an answer?

Comment: Tried await Task.Run(() => GetNewSite(site.SiteId));? You won't have to do this in a Parallel loop.

Comment: @ArpitKhandelwal How would I include `site.address = newSite.address` in your proposed solution? Would you be able to respond as an answer to this post?